# How can I avoid hitting wood when cutting through drywall?

Tags: drywall, cable-management

I was working on concealing some TV wires, and when I cut through the drywall I noticed this wood behind. I did not have this problem in the bedroom. [image: woops]

Answer (score 1):

> **How can I avoid hitting wood when cutting through drywall?**

People typically use low-cost metal detectors and stud detectors to avoid drilling into or opening holes onto electrical wiring, metal structural members or wooden studs etc.

> **It's not a stud. Some kind of panel**

If a previous owner has somehow attached drywall to what was a completely wood-panelled wall of which you have no knowledge, the only way I'd expect to discover this is by accident when making a hole in the wall.

If the panel is localised, a stud-finder might give you some indications that an area is different from the rest of the wall.

You could buy or rent a [DeWalt superman x-ray vision scanner](http://www.digitaltrends.com/home/dewalts-new-radar-scanner-lets-see-walls-like-superman/) <sub>*(I may have the model name slightly wrong)*</sub>

Comment: It's not a stud. Some kind of panel

Comment: @Imessedup: A stud detector will sense changes in density which should show the difference between a void and a piece of wood. A metal detector should find the screws shown in your photo. I imagine there is likely to be other metalwork behind that which would be detected.

Comment: I agree with RedGrittyBrick, but with a caveat.  I have a significant amount of experience with stud detectors (in a wide range of prices), and I have found many of them to be unreliable.  If you buy one, test it out on an area where you know the content.  If it works or doesn't work, post a review on a merchant website.